# .htaccess multiple folders and root

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

can someone help me with an htaccess rules for this application format.

here is my file structure:

```
/api
  - /1.0 (this is a php project, a backend rest api of sorts to the frontend)
      - /other-php-folders
          - /...(lots of stuff)
      - /public
          - /...(lots of assets etc)
      - /index.php
      - /.htaccess (ignore for now)
/src (this contains an angularjs compiled website)
  - /assets
      - /cool-asset.js
      - /cool-asset2.css
      - /cool-asset3.png
  - /index.html
  - /.htaccess
/.htaccess
```

So what i basically want from the root .htaccess file:

- redirect ALL traffic starting with "/api/" to "/api/*". This includes all assets.
- ALL OTHER traffic to go to "/src/*".

  - in /src/.htaccess: i need all file requests to look in /src as usual, but all url requests to simply goto index.html (RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]).

Also another nice feature i would love:

- url: mydomain.com/api/latest to link to a predefined folder (eg. /api/1.0), or if there is a way to find the latest version number from folder names (but having it calculate this might be too much processing power given it can easily be hardcoded and there will be lots of requests).

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of made my own solution, but can someone please comment and let me know if this is good (it works), or if there is a better solution.

Cheers.

/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /src/$1 [L]
```

/src/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```